# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: php, ms-access, com

I have looked through the other answers for this question and none fit the bill.

I am getting this error:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ↲
''<span style=\"line-height: 115%; font-family: \'Verdana\',\'sans-serif\'; ↲
font-size: 7.5pt; mso-ansi-language: TR; mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri; ↲
mso-fareast-theme-font: minor-latin; mso-bidi-font-family: \'Times New Roman\'; ↲
mso-bidi-theme-font: mino'
```

**Edit Here is the Query**:

```
    INSERT INTO the_table (`Kimlik`, `OBJECT_NR`, `pshow`, `rent`, `best`, `pname`,
 `oda1`, `oda2`, `oda3`, `oda4`, `oda5`, `oda6`, `odap`, `lsnr`, `rentg`, `detayb`,
 `ptitle`, `linkno`, `ptype`, `ptip2`, `location`, `stor`, `durum`, `oda`, `plistele`,
 `size`, `fiyat`, `fbasla`, `tocity`, `tosea`, `toair`, `tobus`, `toshop`, `togolf`,
 `topool`, `tomountain`, `tofitness`, `tosauna`, `balkon`, `yil`, `bath`, `pool`, 
`pdetail`, `360`, `plist`, `pmainpic`, `res1`, `res2`, `res3`, `keyword`, `desc`,
 `phomepage`, `ploc`, `pprint`, `tarih`, `video`, `pricerange`, `searange`) VALUES 
('null', 900, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'LRT - ANT900', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 
'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'Konyaalti', '', 'Newly launched off plan development in 
Antalya', 'Newly launched off plan development in Antalya, Antalya Property, Property 
Turkey', 'turkey-property-in-antalya/Newly-launched-off-plan-development-in-Antalya-900.html', 'Apartments', '', 'Antalya', 5, 'Off Plan', 1, 'Newly launched holiday 
development in Antalya, superb investment opportunity, very affordable prices in complex
 with many facilities', '60 sqm', 37000, 'From', '10 mins', '10 mins', '30 mins', 
'walking', 'walking', '45 mins', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'Yes', 2011, 1, '', ' <p>
 Off-plan Antalya Konyalti Apartments, Special Price. </p> <p> New modern complex located
 in the investment area Konyaalti near Blue Flag beaches. Offering hotel facilities this 
property is perfect for investment or holiday home and has rental potential.<br /> The 
complex consists of 2 residential blocks. There is a large pool with children\'s section,
 a water slide for children, children\'s playground, garden, sauna, and fitness room. The
 complex provides 24 hour security and parking facilities for residents. Total area is 3.000m2. Distance to the beach - 1.200m. The complex is located close to Migros, Beach 
Park, Dolphin land.<br /> <br /> <br /> </p> <p style=\"line-height: 150%; background:
 white; margin-left: 36pt\"> Completed date 11/2011, 1 year instalment payment plan<br />
 <br /> Konyaalti is a very popular, welcoming and pleasant area of Antalya. Situated on 
the west of the town, and only 20 minutes from Antalya International Airport. The small 
and fairly quiet suburb of Antalya has a long promenade and beach, with the beautiful 
Taurus mountains as a background scenery. There is very close to hand a good selection of 
shops bars and restaurants, whilst a little further afield are the bigger shopping malls and entertainment parks. The antique harbour of Antalya is also a short distance away </p>
 ', '', '-', '100.jpg', 'Select', '', 'Investment, Holiday, Mountain', 'Real Estate in 
Antalya, Antalya Property, Property in Antalya, Property Antalya', 'Newly launched holiday 
development in Antalya, superb investment opportunity, very affordable prices in complex 
with many facilities from 37000 €', 99, 'Select', '-', '', '', '35.000-40.000', 1.000)

    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> Microsoft
 JET Database Engine<br/><b>Description:</b> Syntax error (missing operator) in query 
expression '' <p> Off-plan Antalya Konyalti Apartments, Special Price. </p> <p> New modern 
complex located in the investment area Konyaalti near Blue Flag beaches. Offering hotel
 facilities this property is perfect for investment or holiday home and has rental '.'
```

Comment: Wow. It's hard for us to debug your code without even seeing it.

Comment: Please give us more information on what you’re doing.

Comment: Well, that's definitely anything *but* a query expression.

Comment: THat is the error message, showing the section of the query that is broken. The query is massively long.

Comment: that's not a query, that's html markup

Comment: You should definitely post the entire query, despite of its length, otherwise we cannot determine the syntax error.

Comment: @anne I have done so, @alexn I have posted query

Answer (score 0):

I assume some character in the html source is breaking your sql query.

- check if your sql query is complete.
- replace all ' and " with \' and \"
- check for extra quotes in your query, I see in the beginning: ''
- if possible output the complete query in your browser (or msgbox) and try the query in phpmyadmin, phpmyadmin will show you a better error message so you may know whats going on ;) but I see you are using access

Answer (score 0):

Access is choking on the two locations where you have

```
children\'s
```

Change those to

```
children''s
```

(two single quotes) and Access should be happy.

Comment: but the single quotes inside the value need to be escaped, as that part of the query is contained in single quotes? Should I make it \'\' ?

Comment: Access is quirky.  I'm not sure about the escaping requirements of php, but this works in access:  `INSERT INTO the_Table ( Thetext )
SELECT 'hello''s' AS Expr1;`  Another approach would be to change all your single quotes wrapping text values into double quotes, then access will let you leave the single quote in `children's`

Comment: In Access (and VB[A]), you escape a quote by doubling it. So to produce a standalone quote is `''''`. First opens the String, second escapes the third, fourth closes String. See also Judah Sali's comment, above.